# MySQL query - getting not inserted ids to insert new row to a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

the first one is process

[image: process table]

and the second one is medialist

[image: medialist table]

I want to insert a new row to process but I need a medialist.id which is not inserted by a user before.

select medialist_id from process where user_id=648 -> this returns the inserted rows.

I want those rows excluded from medialist table and get a random medialist id to insert new row to medialist table.

What is the best cost efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO process (user_id,ads_id,medialist_id,`status`) SELECT 'your_uid','your_ads_id',id,'your_status' FROM medialist WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT medialist_id FROM process) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but if someone else wants to use it. I recommend to add limit 1 at the end. Unfortunately it tooks too long to execute. But I guess there is no other way to do this faster. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Edited my post with limit 1 as well (forgot :P)